# taskmanager alternatives

Tags: windows, task-manager, process-explorer

Other than [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), what good task manager replacements exist?

Comment: How about one for the Blackberry?  I have for WinCE/Mobile.  But could really use one for the BB!

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a separate question about a blackberry task manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer [Extended Task Manager](http://www.extensoft.com/?p=free_task_manager).
[DTaskManager](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) is also ok.

Comment: Extended Task Manager looks neat.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered the open source [Yet Another Process Monitor (YAPM)](http://yaprocmon.sourceforge.net/), I don't like the fact that it requires .NET 3.5 (not a problem on my desktop, but might be a problem on some servers). I'm also not a big fan of the office 2007 style UI.

Interesting features:

- Remote process viewing via WMI or its own server. I have not experimented with either of these but will.
- A panel to view [tasks](http://twitpic.com/h6pfv) like in Task manager. I actually might take a peak at the source code to see how one lists tasks via the windows API.

Answer (score 0):

[CurrProcess](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cprocess.html) is nice (lighter than PE).

It might be helpful to know what problem you're trying to solve. Process Explorer is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I'm not really trying to solve a problem, I just want to know what else is out there..

Comment: Fair enough. Don't forget about tasklist.exe and taskkill.exe .. they are quite handy sometimes :)